# Customizing the Personalization Rules

Tags: personalization

**How can I change the "where the site name compares to value" personalization rule so that "value" is a list of Sites driven by my configuration?**

I have a website in multiple languages with multiple hostnames.  Each hostname corresponds to a different country and different site definition within my configuration (but each site points to the same place in the content tree).  I have named my sites after countries, so:

- mysite.com resolves to the "United States" site
- mysite.co.uk resolves to the "Great Britain" site
- mysite.ca resolves to the "Canada" site

What I am looking for is a way to change the "where the current web site name compares to value" to allow for a Dropdown List of "United States", "Great Britain", and "Canada" rather than a raw text field.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Copy the `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/System/Web
   Site Name`
2. Put 
   `where the current web site name [operatorid,StringOperator,,compares to] [Value,Tree,root=/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/System/Copy of Web Site Name/Sites, value]` into the `Text` field of `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/System/Web Site Name`
3. Implement your custom condition which can resolve the item by ID because by default WebSiteNameCondition expects your site name as a string

   ```
   using Sitecore;
   using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
   using Sitecore.Rules;
   using Sitecore.Sites;

   namespace MyProject.SiteConditions
   {
       public class WebSiteNameCondition<T> : Sitecore.Rules.Conditions.SiteConditions.WebSiteNameCondition<T> where T : RuleContext
       {
           protected override bool Execute(T ruleContext)
           {
               Assert.ArgumentNotNull(ruleContext, "ruleContext");
               if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(base.Value))
               {
                   return false;
               }

               var siteItem = Context.Database.GetItem(base.Value);
               if (siteItem == null)
               {
                   return false;
               }

               var siteName = siteItem["YourSiteField"];

               SiteContext site = Context.Site;
               if (site == null)
               {
                   return false;
               }
               else
               {
                   return this.Compare(site.Name, siteName);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Put your implementation path to the `Type` field, in this case it is `MyProject.SiteConditions.WebSiteNameCondition,MyProject`

### Result

You can select your website as an item in **Rule Set Editor** when you are using this newly created rule:

[image]

I suggest you to also read the following article to understand what are these 4 parameters for - https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecore_what39s_new/posts/creating-custom-conditions-part-1

Comment: 1) Is it the name of the selected item that is taken as the value? 2) Is it a good practice to define the options under the condition item?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko, that's true, I would like to check in the evening. Now it gets the ID of the selected page item. I will provide the corrected answer then after investigation.

Comment: Can I avoid using the standard template?  I already have my countries defined in the tree somewhere else, and want to use a field off of each one.

Comment: @DylanMcCurry Yes, you can use your own path. At the moment this answer is not a solution because when you select the site in Rule Set Editor then it writes the ID of the item as a value and this rule expect the site name as a string. I would like to provide you a full answer just I am still working today.

Comment: @DylanMcCurry, updated my answer.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko I just updated my answer. Thank you for your comment! :)
1) By default no, so I had to adapt the class above 
2) I just put it there to test it, but your root can be anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

I would not change the existing condition.  Instead I would implement a custom condition that functions as you'd like.  The following blog post explains in detail how to create a custom condition.

> https://www.sundoginteractive.com/blog/how-to-customize-personalization-rules-in-sitecore-8

The condition you are going to copy is located here:

> /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Visit/Site Name

You'll need to accomplish every step described in the blog post but the main thing you need to do to display a drop-down to the Marketer instead of a text box is to configure your custom condition with the following syntax:

> where the country name [operatorid,StringOperator,,compares to]
>   **[value,Tree,root=[[full Sitecore path to an item in your Sitecore tree
>   that contains country items]]**,specific country]

What exposes the drop-down GUI instead of the textbox GUI is the **Tree** and **root** elements in the second half of the statement above.

Comment: This is great!  How do I control which field I pull from my selected value?

Comment: @DylanMcCurry, the answer provided by TRNKTMS seems complete to me.  Should be everything you need.